# FreeRTOS: Task Creation Problem

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, freertos

I am creating 2 tasks, one controls a keypad the other a temperature sensor. Each task works individually. However when I try to create both task it does not seem to create the task, it keeps looping in main (discovered while debugging, the task was not being created because there was not enough memory allocated to the heap).
There is an LCD output which flickers when running. However the correct output is displaced when a single task is created. Code below.

main.c

```
    /*HEADER FILES*/
#include    "FreeRTOS.h"
#include    "task.h"
#include    "xlcd_GpE.h"
#include    "Keypad.h"
#include    "TempSensor.h"
#include    "timers.h"
#include    <p18f452.h>

/*PIC18 CONFIGURATION SETTINGS*/
#pragma config OSC = HS
#pragma config WDT = OFF
#pragma config LVP = OFF
#define XTAL_FREQ 4000000

/*VARIABLES*/

/*FUNCTION PROTOTYPES*/
void keypadTask (void *pvParameter);
void tempTask (void *pvParameter);
void keypadISR (void);

void main (void)
{
    INTCONbits.GIE = 0;

    configKeypad();
    InitLCD();
    xTaskCreate( tempTask, "TempTask", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE, NULL, 1, NULL);
    xTaskCreate( keypadTask, "keypadTask", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE, NULL, 1, NULL);

    vTaskStartScheduler();
}
```

temperature function in tempTask.c

```
    void tempTask(void *pvParameter) {

    for (;;) {


             if (xSemaphoreTake(tempSem, (TickType_t) 3000) == pdTRUE) {
            char tempLSB, tempMSB;
            char get[10];
            int k;

            if (owInit() == 1) {
                writeByte(0xCC);
                writeByte(0x44);
                Delay10TCYx(10);
                Nop();
                Nop();
                Nop();
                Nop();
                Nop();
            }
            if (owInit() == 1) {
                writeByte(0xCC);
                writeByte(0xBE);
                for (k = 0; k < 9; k++) {
                    get[k] = readByte();
                }
            }

            tempMSB = get[1];
            tempLSB = get[0];
            if (tempMSB <= 0x80) {
                tempLSB = (tempLSB / 2);
            }
            tempMSB = tempMSB & 0x80;
            if (tempMSB >= 0x80) {
                tempLSB = (~tempLSB) + 1;
            }
            if (tempMSB >= 0x80) {
                tempLSB = (tempLSB / 2);
            }
            if (tempMSB >= 0x80) {
                tempLSB = ((-1) * tempLSB);
            }
            while (BusyXLCD());
            SetDDRamAddr(0x00);
            while (BusyXLCD());
            putsXLCD(tempLSB);
            while (BusyXLCD());

        } else {
            while (BusyXLCD());
            SetDDRamAddr(0x40);
            while (BusyXLCD());
            putrsXLCD("DNG Temp Sem!");
            while (BusyXLCD());
        }
    }
}
```

keypad function in keypad.c

```
    void keypadTask(void *pvParameter) {

    keypadSem = xSemaphoreCreateCounting(1, 0);
    tempSem = xSemaphoreCreateCounting(1, 0);

    for (;;) {
        //vTaskDelay(10);
        if (xSemaphoreTake(keypadSem, (TickType_t) 2500) == pdTRUE) {
            int key = (BIT0 * 1 + BIT1 * 2 + BIT2 * 4 + BIT3 * 8);
            SetDDRamAddr(0x00);
            while (BusyXLCD());
            putrsXLCD("                ");
            switch (key) {
                case 0:
                    xSemaphoreGive(tempSem);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    SetDDRamAddr(0x01);
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    putrsXLCD("2");
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    break;
                case 2:
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    SetDDRamAddr(0x02);
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    putrsXLCD("3");
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    break;
                case 3:
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    SetDDRamAddr(0x03);
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    putrsXLCD("A");
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    break;
                case (4):
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    SetDDRamAddr(0x00);
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    putrsXLCD("4");
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    break;
                case (5):
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    SetDDRamAddr(0x01);
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    putrsXLCD("5");
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    break;
                case (6):
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    SetDDRamAddr(0x02);
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    putrsXLCD("6");
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    break;
                case (7):
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    SetDDRamAddr(0x03);
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    putrsXLCD("B");
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    break;
                case (8):
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    SetDDRamAddr(0x00);
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    putrsXLCD("7");
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    break;
                case (9):
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    SetDDRamAddr(0x01);
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    putrsXLCD("8");
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    break;
                case (10):
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    SetDDRamAddr(0x02);
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    putrsXLCD("9");
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    break;
                case (11):
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    SetDDRamAddr(0x03);
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    putrsXLCD("C");
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    break;
                case (12):
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    SetDDRamAddr(0x00);
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    putrsXLCD("0");
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    break;
                case (13):
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    SetDDRamAddr(0x01);
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    putrsXLCD("F");
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    break;
                case (14):
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    SetDDRamAddr(0x02);
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    putrsXLCD("E");
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    break;
                case (15):
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    SetDDRamAddr(0x03);
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    putrsXLCD("D");
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    break;
                default:
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    SetDDRamAddr(0x00);
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    putrsXLCD("An Error!");
                    while (BusyXLCD());
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            while (BusyXLCD());
            SetDDRamAddr(0x00);
            while (BusyXLCD());
            putrsXLCD("DNG Keypad Sem!");
            while (BusyXLCD());
            INTCONbits.INT0F = 0;
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: You should be confirming that `xTaskCreate` returns `pdPASS`. Right now you have no idea if it creates the tasks or not.

Comment: What is configUSE_PREEMPTION set to?? (Look in FreeRTOSConfig.h.)

Comment: configUSE_PREEMPTION is set to 1, so I'm using preemption. @Ron Beyer, will add that in actually will help with the debugging!

Comment: @SimeonR Thanks. It was important to say so. Without it, there's no pre-emption. And without pre-emption using a timer, you have to explicitly provide calls to allow the O/S to switch between process stacks. It was the first step to be sure of, in my mind. Off-hand, do you know what the default priority for the main() process is? (I don't use FreeRTOS and thought I'd just ask you.)

Comment: @SimeonR Oh... and I see that configUSE_TIME_SLICING also affects round-robin scheduling. What's its value?

Comment: @jonk I have configUSE_TIME_SLICING set to 0, I'm not sure I know the priority of the main() process, I assumed that once I called vTaskStartScheduler() I would never actually return to the main function and continue looping in whichever task I created and the idle task when the task are blocked for whatever reason. It's no problem really :D

Comment: @SimeonR I think I [read here](https://www.freertos.org/RTOS-task-priority.html) that it should be 1 if you want round-robin scheduling of processes with equal priority. Can you read that page, yourself, and tell me your take on it as it applies to your situation? (I don't use FreeRTOS. Instead, I have written my own configurable O/S decades ago that can compile for much smaller targets than can FreeRTOS.)

Comment: Can you also say which PIC you are using, and what `configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE` is?

Comment: @RonBeyer, I'm using the PIC18f452 and my configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE is set to 128, that value I got from the default FreeRTOSConfig.h on the FreeRTOS website, I didn't actually do the analysis to verify if that size was appropriate but for the practice runs that I've had before hand it has been adequate (meaning I didn't run into problems).

Comment: @jonk I believe time slicing will alternate between equal priority task on the tick interrupt if time slicing is set to 1. I know that in my initial post I had the task at the same priority but that is a bit of a mistake on my part since the keypad function should be at a higher priority. But the situation remains the same when I enable slicing and even when I use tasks with differing priorities.

Comment: @SimeonR Thanks for checking and testing an alternate approach and for noting that the keypad should be at a higher priority. All good stuff. This leaves me with 2nd order questions, though. For example, is the minimal stack size sufficient for the function calls your processes make? (Probably. But what do I know?) How familiar are you with FreeRTOS? Have you used it successfully on other projects, before? Is there a demo source that allows you to test your "setup" and tool chain? Stuff like that. Which means I don't really have a ready answer, right now. But I can +1 your question.

Comment: @jonk, Well that question really got me thinking, because I haven't done the demo, but I have built a project using multiple tasks (max 3) and it worked successfully with basically the same set up, I will try to add on some room to my minimal stack size and see if that shines a light on the problem, will run it and return with more information soon, thanks again! I'm adding in the code that will confirm that the task is being successfully created so that I can have some information about what is occurring in main also.

Comment: I can confirm that the task creation has failed (using the exception handling), I will update the original post. From the FreeRTOS manual, they explained that this can be due to an insufficient amount of memory being allocated to the heap.

Comment: Wow! adding more memory worked, previously my code configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE was set to 512, I doubled the amount to 1024 and my tasks were created and ran correctly*. *Not correctly since it isn't converting the temperature but that's a different problem, thank you @jonk and Ron Beyer

Comment: @SimeonR Great to hear! Coincidentally, I can go into intimate details about how to structure and write an O/S (which varies on what you consider to be the most fundamental abstractions at its core.) I worked on the Unix v6 kernel and, before that, created timeshared BASIC and assembly code on an HP 21xx back in 1975. Later, I taught operating system design at a 4yr university and I've been doing O/S work almost every year since. So it's old hat. But that doesn't mean I have a magic wand to wave. It just means some ideas are familiar to me and that I can imagine a little more than some.

Comment: @SimeonR My smaller configurable O/S is designed to sit very well with C to minimize the assembly I need to write when retargeting. It allows heap, but only a global heap, for example. (There is no per-process heap allocator as that would mean more work, more code, more data, and less reliance on the compiler vendor's library system and it doesn't pay for itself well for the application spaces I address.) If you ever get a chance, I recommend you read (for joy, only) Douglas Comer's original red-cover "XINU" book (1983, I think?) It is a joy to read and clear as a bell. Worth the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirming the task was actually being created by using the pdPASS was a great tool, from there, the answer was found in the FreeRTOS Reference Manual, under the vTaskCreate example. Problem was solved by changing configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE from 512 to 1024, in the FreeRTOSconfig.h (for the PIC18f452)

```
    /* Define a structure called xStruct and a variable of type xStruct. These are just used to
demonstrate a parameter being passed into a task function. */
typedef struct A_STRUCT
{
 char cStructMember1;
 char cStructMember2;
} xStruct;

/* Define a variable of the type xStruct to pass as the task parameter. */
xStruct xParameter = { 1, 2 };

/* Define the task that will be created. Note the name of the function that implements the task
is used as the first parameter in the call to xTaskCreate() below. */
void vTaskCode( void * pvParameters )
{
xStruct *pxParameters;

 /* Cast the void * parameter back to the required type. */
 pxParameters = ( xStruct * ) pvParameters;

 /* The parameter can now be accessed as expected. */
 if( pxParameters->cStructMember1 != 1 )
 {
 /* Etc. */
 }

 /* Enter an infinite loop to perform the task processing. */
 for( ;; )
 {
 /* Task code goes here. */
 }
}
/* Define a function that creates a task. This could be called either before or after the
scheduler has been started. */
void vAnotherFunction( void )
{
TaskHandle_t xHandle;

 /* Create the task. */
 if( xTaskCreate(
 vTaskCode,                   /* Pointer to the function that implements the task. */
 "Demo task",                 /* Text name given to the task. */
 STACK_SIZE,                  /* The size of the stack that should be created for the task.
                              This is defined in words, not bytes. */
 (void*) &xParameter,        /* A reference to xParameters is used as the task parameter.
                              This is cast to a void * to prevent compiler warnings. */
 TASK_PRIORITY,              /* The priority to assign to the newly created task. */
 &xHandle                    /* The handle to the task being created will be placed in
 xHandle.                     */
 ) != pdPASS )
 {
 /* The task could not be created as there was insufficient heap memory remaining. If
 heap_1.c, heap_2.c or heap_4.c are included in the project then this situation can be
 trapped using the vApplicationMallocFailedHook() callback (or ‘hook’) function, and the
 amount of FreeRTOS heap memory that remains unallocated can be queried using the
 xPortGetFreeHeapSize() API function.*/
 }
 else
 {
 /* The task was created successfully. The handle can now be used in other API functions,
 for example to change the priority of the task.*/
 vTaskPrioritySet( xHandle, 2 );
 }
}
```